# Are 'finitely measurable functions' closed under addition?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I'm investigating the properties of Lebesgue measure without countable additivity. That is, I have an outer measure on $\Bbb R$ that satisfies (for subsets $A,B$):

- $m^*(A)\in[0,\infty]$
- $m^*(A\cup B)\le m(A)+m(B)$
- $m^*(A)=0$ when $A$ is countable
- $m^*(A)\le m^*(B)$ when $A\subseteq B$
- $m^*(A+x)=m^*(A)$
- $m^*([a,b])=b-a$

The actual measure $m(A)$ is as usual defined to be equal to $m^*(A)$ when $m(A)=m(A\cap E)+m(A\setminus E)$ for all sets $E$ (in which case $A$ is called measurable). From this it is derived that:

- $A$ is measurable when $m^*(A)=0$
- $A\cup B$ and $A^c$ are measurable if $A,B$ are
- intervals are measurable

Notably absent from this list are theorems concerning countable unions and intersections, except, curiously, that countable sets are still null. Other than that, it seems to act a lot like Jordan measure. Given this setting, I want to define measurable functions analogous to the standard definition: a function $f$ is measurable when $f^{-1}((a,\infty))$ is measurable for each $a\in\bar{\Bbb R}$.

But the snag here is that most proofs need countable additivity for even the most basic properties, and the textbook definition of measure usually includes countable additivity, so I have no references. In particular, I would like to know if $f+g$ and $-f$ are measurable given that $f$ and $g$ are. The usual proof uses $(-\infty,a)=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\left(\Bbb R\setminus(a-\frac1n,\infty)\right)$, so that won't work for me. I am a little blind because I have no counterexamples in mind, so any help with a go-to counterexample here would be great too.

Comment: Possibly Orrin Frink's paper [*Jordan measure and Riemann integration*](http://math.uga.edu/~pete/Frink33.pdf) could be of use. Also, Rao's book [**Theory of Charges**](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0124109845) should be useful.

Comment: Your definition of measurability seems unnatural without countable additivity, one would rather take some finitely additive algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ and require that inverse image of every set in it is measurable. And since you seem to follow the standard Lebesgue measure construction why isn't the resulting measure $m$ countably additive?

Comment: @Conifold I didn't want to get into the details of why because mention of it seems to turn people off, but I'm denying countable choice, which is needed for the proof of countable additivity of the Lebesgue measure. The actual definition of $m^*$ is otherwise identical to standard textbook definitions of Lebesgue measure. You make a convincing point that my choice of basis sets is unnatural since I can't invert an open interval the usual way. Did you have a specific algebra in mind? I'm thinking that using all open intervals, or $[a,\infty)$ and $(a,\infty)$ might make it more symmetric.

Comment: My goal is to prove that the Lebesgue integral has at least the properties of the Riemann integral (that is, sufficient to integrate Riemann-integrable functions) without invoking choice at all. It's not clear to me yet if this is possible.

Comment: This explains it, so one can get $m^*$ without countable choice? I'd just take the algebra generated by your semi-infinite intervals, which I think is all closed, semi-closed and open intervals, and their disjoint finite unions. There was some work done on reconstructing analysis without choice, although specific references escape me at the moment.